# which non parametric test to use?

Tags: nonparametric, methodology

I'll start with saying I am not an expert in stats and had some basic knowledge of Anova but was now told to use the nonparametric test in my project and I'm lost.
My design:
I have two groups, low and high level of the second language (independent v.)
tested in two conditions: gesture/ no gesture (independent v.)

for a fluency measure(speech rate) at one point in time (dependent v.)

Which would be the appropriate test to run in this case?

Comment: What are the null and alternative hypotheses you want to test??

Comment: The null hypothesis is that the gesture/no gesture condition will not have an effect on either group. I know that in parametric tests it would be 2x2 mixed design ANOVA but as my sample is small I was advised to use nonparametric test, and I am lost...

Comment: All of that information belongs in your question; good advice needs that context

Answer (score 0):

If speech rate is ordinal, then Kruskall Wallis can help you in this scenario. Considering each combination of second languange and the two conditions, you can test whether the distribution of these four groups are the same, based on ranks.

> The Kruskal-Wallis H test (sometimes also called the "one-way ANOVA on
>   ranks") is a rank-based nonparametric test that can be used to
>   determine if there are statistically significant differences between
>   two or more groups of an independent variable on a continuous or
>   ordinal dependent variable. [(from spss)](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/kruskal-wallis-h-test-using-spss-statistics.php)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought of that but I get two measures for speech rate: one with and one without gesture condition, will this work for that test?

Comment: Considering those as different groups, yes.

Comment: No, since there are two independent variables, you cannot put both into a single Kruskal-Wallis test.

Answer (score 0):

One option: you can use an aligned ranks approach.  This is similar in spirit to the Kruskal-Wallis test, but will allow for more complex models. [The ARTool  software](http://depts.washington.edu/madlab/proj/art/) makes this easy, especially with its implementation in R.

Another approach would be to use an appropriate model for the kind of data you have.  For example, if your dependent variable is ordinal in nature, ordinal regression would be a good solution.

A good implementation of either of these should be able to handle a design analogous to a 2 x 2 mixed model.

Finally, someone telling you to use nonparametric statistics may not be a very good reason to do so.  You might want to explore the reasoning more.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am using non-parametric as I have a small sample of 10, as part of my analysis I am doing qualitative analysis as well, hence the smaller sample size. The qualitative is more exploratory in nature and therefore I have to use non-parametric.  My dependent variable is a speech rate with different values so I am not sure which test I could use for that?

Comment: It's hard to say.  A rate might be gamma distributed, and could be amenable to gamma regression.  Or my suggestions above.